# Getting 7-12V from a computer monitor

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, monitor

Does anybody have an idea how to safely get 7-12V from an ordinary LCD computer monitor?

I wish to control the monitor via a microcontroller after the fashion of the [guide at lucidscience](http://www.lucidscience.com/pro-vga%20video%20generator-1.aspx). I'd like to have the microcontroller draw its power from the monitor, rather than add another power source. (The arduino needs 5V to run at the clock speed prescribed by the guide, so I understand that to require 7-12V preregulated.)

Perhaps I could simply stick a multitester here and there, but I'm green enough that that looks pretty hopeless.

Comment: You are 'green enough' to be 'pretty hopeless' finding the power supply in a monitor and still you want to connect an Arduino inside a monitor. This sounds like a generally bad idea. There are lethal voltages inside a monitor and you shouldn't open it if you don't know how the apparatus works.

Comment: I am badly ashamed.

Comment: I advise you to never try this with a CRT. Electron guns run at ~20kV, and I've got first hand experience of how painful that can be.

Answer (score 1):

Find out how much power the power supply for your monitor puts out and then hook up a boost converter (to step up the voltage) or a buck converter (or maybe voltage regulator) (to reduce the voltage) to power the arduino. Sometimes you even find marked points on the screens power supply to tap into. (The general: Be aware of high voltages applies here too.)

Comment: I'll take a look and return to this thread afterward. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Many monitors have built in USB hubs.  Get one of those and use the +5v directly from the USB port.  Done.

Comment: I'm actually modifying the monitor in other ways too, so I'm using freebies (to avoid damaging a good monitor). I have none with USB hubs, but that would do it.

Comment: Freebies as in CRT or as in flat panel/LCD/TFT?

Comment: LCD. (Junked at work.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with an LCD monitor you aren't facing any danger from the voltages inside (an old CRT monitor is a very different story).

That said, in either case the most guaranteed source of DC voltage is [pin #9 on the VGA connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) or [pin #14 on the DVI connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface).  Both of these should be at 5V so you will need a buck convertor to raise the voltage to power the Arduino (although the 5V would be fine to power an ATMega328 directly).

I have exactly no idea how much current either of these is pins can allow so doing this **may burn out your video card** so attempt this on a cheap / old card first and be prepared for failure.

Comment: Depending on the backlight technology, there may actually be dangerous voltages inside.

Comment: Whoops!  I stand corrected Chris.  However are we talking 120v dangerous or something even less benign?